# How to start/configure pulseaudio remotely with ssh?

Tags: sound, ssh, pulseaudio, environment-variables

I have a remote machine to which I can ssh. On the remote machine there is a program that uses pulse audio to get input from a USB microphone attached to the remote machine. This setup works fine when operated locally, i.e. I can get input from pulse audio when connected locally.

Over ssh, I receive the error:

```
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused
```

Equally, when I try to open `pavucontrol` on the remote machine via `ssh -X`, I get the message:

> Connection to PulseAudio failed. ... In this case this is likely
> because PULSE_SERVER in the Environment/X11 Root Window Properties or
> default-server in client.conf is misconfingured.

```
pulseaudio --start
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at {30ab51874e4a0ca492830f1400000007}unix:/home/user2/.pulse/30ab51874e4a0ca492830f1400000007-runtime/native, refusing to start/autospawn.
```

Attempting to start pulse audio with x11: `start-pulseaudio-x11`

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

`pulseaudio --check` returns straight to the command prompt.

If I attempt to get the ssh X properties, I get:

```
user1@remote-pc:~$: xprop -root | grep PULSE
PULSE_COOKIE(STRING) = Some stuff here
PULSE_SERVER(STRING) = "{30ab51874e4a0ca492830f1400000007}unix:/home/user2/.pulse/30ab51874e4a0ca492830f1400000007-runtime/native"
PULSE_SESSION_ID(STRING) = "30ab51874e4a0ca492830f1400000007-1407765989.424751-1424846683"
PULSE_ID(STRING) = "12165@30ab51874e4a0ca492830f1400000007/2040"
```

Ok.  I have seen questions related to this issue, but in each case, the asker wants to transmit sound across a network connection, which I do >not< want to do.  So what do I configure `PULSE_SERVER` to be?

Answer (score 10):

I seem to have resolved the problem by running

```
pax11publish -r
```

Now, `xprop -root | grep PULSE` shows:

```
PULSE_SERVER(STRING) = "{9899a0f46bdae6bbc8e6e8b200000005}unix:/home/user1/.pulse/9899a0f46bdae6bbc8e6e8b200000005-runtime/native"
```

Apparently `pulseaudio --check` should normally go to the command prompt.  Apparently this indicates it is running.

Comment: The OP had posted this as part of the question. I removed it and posted as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your ~/.bashrc in the remote server (if you use Bash as default shell):

```
if test "$SSH_CLIENT" ; then export PULSE_SERVER=tcp:localhost; fi
```

or put

```
default-server = tcp:localhost
```

in */etc/pulse/client.conf* or in the files with same name under *pulse* directory under user-specific configuration file directory if such file(s) are used. See https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html for more information about the directories.