# How To Disable PulseAudio Remote Sound

Tags: pulseaudio, x11-forwarding

I have been running my music player (Clementine) headless on a file server that is plugged into my stereo.  I open the player up on my workstation via ssh X11 forwarding (`ssh -f -X me@fileserver 'clementine'`) and it used to play fine out of my stereo's speakers.

I enabled pulseaudio on my workstation this evening and now I can't get any sound from Clementine because it's picking up the PA driver on my workstation and is trying to play through that.  How do I tell the PA libs on my fileserver to always use the local sound system rather than the network one?  I can still listen to music by logging into the file server with VNC and starting Clementine from there, but that is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Set and export the `PULSE_SERVER` environment variable to be the path of the Unix domain socket of the `pulseaudio` server that is running on your file server.  For example, I use:

```
export PULSE_SERVER=/run/user/1000/pulse/native
```

The exact path will depend on how `pulseaudio` is configured on your file server.

After you export `PULSE_SERVER`, then run Clementine.

Documentation of `PULSE_SERVER` is [here on freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/ServerStrings/).

For another possible solution (that I have not verified) see this answer:
[How to start/configure pulseaudio remotely with ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509827/how-to-start-configure-pulseaudio-remotely-with-ssh/795919#795919)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of a fix for anyone else with this problem.  I wrote a quick script which removes the pulseaudio xprops and then starts Clementine.  It's below in case anyone else needs it, although I would prefer a "don't do that!" checkbox...

```
#!/bin/bash
for p in PULSE_COOKIE PULSE_SERVER PULSE_SESSION_ID PULSE_ID; do
  xprop -root -remove $p
done
clementine
```